# Word document open in read only mode on another system in same network using word.interop in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a module in DNN 8.0.4, I have use word.interop to replace word document template textbox values from database values. Works fine for single user but when two users try to use that module same time in same network then only one user can access document but other get error and that document open in read only mode on others system in network.

How I can use single word document for multiple users at each new request from users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can give each user his own word document with a path based on his NT user.

Comment: I assume the file that your module opens in NOT a template? If not simply make it a template. Then when the user opens the template using your module it should automatically rename it "document1" therefore allowing other users to access the template file. I hope this is what you are talking about.

Comment: How we can make word document as a template?